# Understanding JavaScript as a C++ coder with compare and contrast

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, functional-programming

Having troubles understanding `<> </>` typescript html like tags in JavaScript when you use them to do object oriented programming like structures.

What does an expression like `<> </>` empty angle brackets mean in the following? Is it a generic tag like `<T> <T/>`? Why JavaScript object functions always have a single object input like html tags where function objects like `return ()` `render ()` always get a single parameter input that uses html tags like `function ( <tag> </tag> )` ? In Java or C++ you can give a function inputs like `function (p1, p2) { ...}` where `(p1, p2)` are two object inputs/attributes that can be manipulated inside the function structure. So I can assume `<tag> </tag>` is a customary format structure for JavaScript function objects input where these tags define an object in scripting language?

In the following code from the react js online tutorial, I see that a new `MouseTracker` class component being extended from React.Component DOM object. Then they said that `<Mouse/>` is a new component inside MouseTracker class that we just defined for the first time only using html tags like `<Mouse/>` where Mouse is an object/component? So objects in Java /C++ and components in JavaScript are the similar concepts where you can just define an object component using `<Object/>` ? I posted the code block in the following:

```
class MouseTracker extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Move the mouse around!</h1>
        <Mouse />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

I see new object or component classes are being used like

```
function  { <tag attribute: 'x' > < App/> <tag/> }
```

where `<App/>` is a component object. Then `<tag ...> ...< tag/>` is a function `props` like class component properties I guess?

I am new to the world of JavaScript and functional programming. I mostly code in C++ (object oriented programming). As I'm trying to learn JavaScript through compare and contrast process to build my MVP business website in reatjs/nodejs, I'm trying to understand JavaScript components as they're used (contrasting with C++ class objects). For example,
`< Mouse/>` is a component. Then `class Mouse expends React.Component { }` also defines a component Mouse using `constructor()` object oriented like function as you would do on Java/C++. Then in Java you would create an instance of new object by

`Object name = new Object (p1, p2);`

In case of an imaginary mouse class in JavaScript, you'd do like

`Mouse mouse= new Mouse (p1, p2);` . Then you can use `mouse` as an instance. Does `<Mouse/>` in JavaScript mean that `<Mouse/>` is an instance/component object as you would do the same using `mouse` instance in Java like `Mouse mouse= new Mouse (p1, p2);` ?

Comment: Please visit [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - I tried to fix your question

Comment: Can someone please format/fix my question? I have been away from this community for some time now and really forgot how to format code/questions properly on Stack Overflow

Comment: `<App />` and almost everything you asked about is not JS or TS, it's JSX. https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: That's not javascript, that's JSX - a language created by Facebook that looks like a cross between javascript and PHP (only a bit more sane)

Comment: @slebetman php? Are you sure you don't confuse it with hhvm xhp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tags aren't javascript. They are 'React' specific, equivalent to Fragment, which emulates HTML fragments. Historically in each React component everything would have to be wrapped in a single root element or react component like this (Using a < div > for example):

```
const MyReactComponent = () => (
<div>
 <h1>my code</h1>
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
)
```

This wasn't allowed and will break the react compiler:
It needs a root wrapper

```
const MyReactComponent = () => (
 <h1>my code</h1>
  <p>hello</p>
)
```

Though you can now do this its problematic with various editors, vscode, linting rules, proptypes/typescript or other and generally not used:

```
const MyReactComponent = () => ([
 <h1 key="arrayitem1">my code</h1>,
  <p key="arrayitem1">hello</p
])
```

So the problem is the old html bad practice of divitis. Loads and loads of unnecessary div wrappers. A fragment is not a rendered element and therefore less taxing of brower repaint and rerender.  That is the reason for using <> as a wrapper.

This is why developers use this:

```
const MyReactComponent = () => (
<>
 <h1>my code</h1>
  <p>hello</p>
</>
)
```

Which really equates to this. Is the same thing:

```
import {Fragment} from 'react'
const MyReactComponent = () => (
<Fragment>
 <h1>my code</h1>
  <p>hello</p>
</Fragment>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not Javascript or real HTML exactly. This is an extension called JSX. It allows you to simulate adding HTML tags, but under the hood it's all javascript functions calling eachother. Since you're using react, I would recommend you play around with this [compiler](https://babeljs.io/) because it will give you a better idea on what React does with JSX tags, and  [this article](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#why-jsx) that explains why React preferres to use JSX.